# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when connecting to WebSocket via Weberknecht

Tags: java, android, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a WebSocket via [Weberknecht Java library](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/main/de/roderick/weberknecht). When the Java client tries to create the connection, I get the following error message:

```
W/System.err(805): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1000; index=1000
W/System.err(805): at ...WebSocketConnection.connect(WebSocketConnection.java:86)
```

Here is the part which causes the problem:

```
public void connect() throws WebSocketException {
    try {
        if (connected) {
            throw new WebSocketException("already connected");
        }

        socket = createSocket();
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        output.write(handshake.getHandshake());

        boolean handshakeComplete = false;
        int len = 10000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        int pos = 0;
        ArrayList<String> handshakeLines = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (!handshakeComplete) {
            int b = input.read();
            buffer[pos] = (byte) b; // THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
            pos += 1;

            if (buffer[pos - 1] == 0x0A && buffer[pos - 2] == 0x0D) {
                String line = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                if (line.trim().equals("")) {
                    handshakeComplete = true;
                } else {
                    handshakeLines.add(line.trim());
                }

                buffer = new byte[len];
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
```

What could cause this issue? Is it that this client library may not comply with the WebSocket version that the server uses?

The [issue over there at Weberknecht](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/issues/detail?id=17) has not been solved yet. I want to ask this question here because it seems to be quite a general problem (reading WebSocket headers and handshake data).

Comment: Tell me, The statement in the 86th line

Comment: It is `buffer[pos] = (byte) b;` as marked in the code.

Comment: You should be aware that there is a security problem with this library. See: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needs to check for `-1` from input.read() to denote the connection hitting EOF.

Also I will assume based on the same bit of code that if a handshake hasn't been reaching after `10000` bytes it is an invalid handshake.

```
while (!handshakeComplete) {
            int b = input.read();

            if (b == -1)
                throw new WebSocketException ("Connected closed.");                

            if (pos == buffer.length)
                throw new WebSocketException ("Invalid handshake.");

            buffer[pos] = (byte) b; // THIS LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
            pos += 1;

            if (buffer[pos - 1] == 0x0A && buffer[pos - 2] == 0x0D) {
                String line = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
                if (line.trim().equals("")) {
                    handshakeComplete = true;
                } else {
                    handshakeLines.add(line.trim());
                }

                buffer = new byte[len];
                pos = 0;
            }
        }
```

**Update**

Here is a better implementation:

```
public void connect() throws WebSocketException {
    try {
        if (connected) {
            throw new WebSocketException("already connected");
        }

        socket = createSocket();
        input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        output.write(handshake.getHandshake());

        boolean handshakeComplete = false;

        ArrayList<String> handshakeLines = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);

        String handshakeData;
        while ((handshakeData = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (handshakeData.trim().equals("")) {
               handshakeComplete = true;
               break;
            }
            handshakeLines.add(handshakeData);
        }

        if (!handshakeComplete)
            throw new WebSocketException ("Failed to establish handshake.");
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just thinking, why don't you use `int read(byte[] b)` which reads the the bytes for you. `int read(byte[] b) --> Reads some number of bytes from the contained input stream and stores them into the buffer array b.`

```
 while (!handshakeComplete) {
   int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);//returns number of bytes read
   if(bytesRead  < 10000 || bytesRead == -1 ||
      (buffer[bytesRead - 1] == 0x0A && buffer[bytesRead - 2] == 0x0D)){
        //done with reading
        handshakeComplete = true;
   }
   if(bytesRead != -1){
      String line = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
      if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
         handshakeLines.add(line.trim());
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking briefly, you make no guarantees of stopping before `buffer.length == pos`.  That would be one thing to double check - `pos` has to stay strictly less than the length of the buffer.